# How to map the type in grails to the user defined type in oracle database

Tags: oracle, grails

I have a domain called People

```
class People 
{
Integer id
Person person

static mapping = {
    id generator: 'sequence',
       params: [table: 'PEOPLE', column: 'ID', max_lo: 100]
       person column: "currency", sqlType: "char", length: 3

    person column : 'PERSON', sqlType: "PERSONOBJ"

}
}
```

AND A domain called person

```
class Person {
String last_Name
String first_Name
}
```

I want to know how to use GORM to map people to oracle 
[People Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO7Tl.png)

Person data type is PersonObj. This is the user-define type like the following :

```
create or replace TYPE PersonObj AS OBJECT (
   first_name  VARCHAR2(50),
   last_name   VARCHAR2(50)
 );
```

The question is how to map the domain class people to the people table in grails?

Comment: It should map automatically to table. In fact you only need to create domain class. doing `run-app` will create table for you in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
class People {
    Person person
}

Class Person{

    static hasOne = [people:People]

}
```